# Cannot run Ubuntu install dual boot from USB on X1 Carbon w/Win8.1 - kernel panic, VFS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, kernel, lenovo, 15.04

I installed Ubuntu as dual-boot on X1 Carbon 3rd gen (with Windows 8.1, UEFI etc.; lets call it "Machine A"). I had some issue with Ubuntu there, so I removed like 3 partitions (from Windows tool) - one had 1MB, the other was main, the other was seemingly SWAP partition. I did not remove any other partitions that looked like the ones aimed at dealing with some internal stuff (such as deep sleep or recovery).

When I created startup disk (USB) on some other Ubuntu machine (lets call it "Machine B"), and restarted Machine A to boot from USB stick, then selected custom boot source (the mentioned USB), I saw boot loader (GRUB?) with option to "Install Ubuntu", but when I selected it, I saw the following:

```
[    0.329678] Error parsing PCC subspaces from PCCT
[    0.329694] ACPI PCC probe failed.
[    0.477876] Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
[    0.477900] CPU: 1 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 3.19.0-15-generic #15-Uuntu
[    0.477919] Hardware name: LENOVO 20BS0068PB/20BS0068PB, BIOS N14ET26W (1.04 ) 01/23/2015
[    0.477939]  fffea000313a480 ffff8802241efdb8 ffffffff817c2205 0000000000002892
(...)
[    0.478009] Call Trace:
(...)
[    0.478155]  [<ffffffff817b6ae0>] ? rest_init+0x80/0x80
[    0.478175] Kernel Offset: 0x0 from 0xffffffff81000000 (relocation range: 0xffffffff80000000-0xffffffffbfffffff)
[    0.478200] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
```

So, as you see, there is some kernel panic related to this installation, and I am not sure what could I do to even debug the issue.

Windows 8.1 is starting properly, when selected as boot source. But I have some issues with virtual machines running Ubuntu (they look like experiencing same issue my machine had with that first Ubuntu installation).

Any ideas on how to fix the problem, or at least be able to fetch more information on it?

Ps. The example of exact image I am seeing is here:

[image: image showing exact error I see during boot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It came out the problem is with the USB stick - after using Windows recovery and reverting all the disks to original state, reinstalling Windows etc. it still appeared. Then I just recreated installation USB on different USB drive and it started to work.

I don't know what was the reason this drive was corrupted, but in similar situation using another USB drive should be one of the easiest bets.

Ps. That original USB drive had two partitions at some point: one for SWAP. Maybe it somehow interferred with installation.